# How to package an app in vs code using titanium for android Mobile Apps?

Tags: android, visual-studio-code, titanium

While packaging it is asking output location twice I am confused which one to use, I am doing it on vs code using titanium extension which I downloaded.

Answer (score 2):

Simple steps:

1. select the package symbol ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1h01W.png))
2. select the path where the apk will be created
3. select your android.keystore file ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZ9vu.png))
4. enter your keystore-alias ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hHqO.png))
5. enter the keystore-password ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMuYk.png))
6. repeat step 5

done